# Convert raster linear unit from meter to foot while keeping Albers projection in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

I have a DEM data that is in NAD 1983 UTM Zone 14N, its linear unit is meters. I would like to use it in another software that wants a DEM that is in USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic USGS project and with linear unit of US Survey Feet.

I tried to convert UTM to State Plane first to convert the linear unit from meters to feet, which was successful, but the problem is how to re-project it to the Albers projection, which in ArcGIS Pro has meter as linear unit.

I actually has an example terrain geotif DEM data that is actually in Albers project with US Survey Feet as linear unit, I don't know how it is made that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcGIS Pro, one can project a raster directly from UTM to Albers, the key is to modify the 'Output Coordinate System' first. It is done by right-mouse click on the USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic USGS projection in the Coordinate System dialog, and choose 'Copy and Modify...', then one can change the linear unit to 'US Survey Feet'.